# Tensorflow only showing (and using) cpu when gpu is available

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I use tensorflow it only uses the cpu. I am running windows 11 and I have NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU.

When I run:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
import tensorflow as tf

print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
print(tf.sysconfig.get_build_info())
```

The output is:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 278769507336930520
xla_global_id: -1
]

OrderedDict([('is_cuda_build', False), ('is_rocm_build', False), ('is_tensorrt_build', False), ('msvcp_dll_names', 'msvcp140.dll,msvcp140_1.dll')])
```

This shows that tensorflow only uses CPU. I have all the libraries (cuda and cudnn) and when I run `nvcc -V` inside the command line it outputs:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:41:10_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0
```

I have cudnn 8.6 installed. Running `cudnn.h` `cudnn.lib` `cudnn64_8.dll` it opens the files normally. These are the tensor* python libraries I have installed:

```
tensorboard                  2.13.0
tensorboard-data-server      0.7.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit       1.8.1
tensorflow                   2.13.0
tensorflow-datasets          4.9.2
tensorflow-estimator         2.13.0
tensorflow-intel             2.13.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.31.0
tensorflow-metadata          1.13.1
```

I had cuda 12.2 installed and tried installing cuda 11.8 but it didn't help. I searched the web and found similar problems but nothing helped. I found something about tensorflow_gpu but I also found that it is not used.

**EDIT**: if it is important I use GeForce Experience and have the latest drivers: GeForce Game Ready Driver 536.67

Comment: Have you checked here to see if everything you have matches? https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tensorflow 2.13 installed, but for native windows installs, GPU acceleration is only supported up to tensorflow 2.10 ([see here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows)).

From the link under GPU Support:

> Note: GPU support on native-Windows is only available for 2.10 or earlier versions, starting in TF 2.11, CUDA build is not supported for Windows. For using TensorFlow GPU on Windows, you will need to build/install TensorFlow in WSL2 or use tensorflow-cpu with TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin

Try downgrading the install to tf 2.10, or use linux (you can dual boot, use a VM or wsl). Hope this helps.

Derek

Comment: How can I downgrade to tensorflow 2.10? When I run `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow==2.10.0` it gives an error `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.10.0 (from versions: 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1, 2.13.0rc2, 2.13.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.10.0` Is it because I have python 3.11.1?

Comment: Yes. tf 2.10 is only compatible for python versions 3.7-3.10 (same website I linked earlier). I recommend using anaconda, then you can make different environments and play around with them in an isolated sense. Something to look into. For now, downgrade python to 3.10 and tf to 2.10 and that should help. Make sure to use compatible cuda and cudnn versions too.

Answer (score 1):

you have the first check if your GPU is available in your Tensorflow with:

```
print("tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')")
```

then if you see something like: `"/GPU:0"`
your GPU is available in Tensorflow

second:, in Tensorflow >> 2.9, the library automatically finds a GPU and uses it for training. so I recommend seeing [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) and [this](https://saturncloud.io/blog/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible/) links and checking what version is compatible with the CUDA and TensorFlow versions.

third: I recommend you install stable versions of TensorFlow (like 2.9, 2.10)

fourth: you can use Ubuntu for Better hardware and resource management.

five: check the CUDA is successfully installed, if you completely successfully install the CUDA in Windows, the `nvidia-smi` command is working on cmd